# How to find all of the tables that are used in a view in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, view, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find a way of finding all of the tables that are used by a particular view in a list. Is there a Redshift Table/a query that I could run that I could use to find this information? I want to be able to insert the name of a view, and have all the tables used in this view returned as the output. Thank you.